# How to query simplemembership database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

MVC4 using db first with simplemembership

I have my membership working to the point where I can save a a new user.  Once the person is registered, I need to render a new view so they can fill in more information, so I need the newly created userid from the UserProfile table to be passed to the new view.  I have tried modifying the templated register method to this:

```
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Email = model.Email }, true);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

//Get the userid for this new user
                var db = new UsersContext();
                int id = db.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserName == model.UserName).Select(x => x.UserId).FirstOrDefault();

                return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Profile", id);
            }
```

This gives me this error:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'UserProfile' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserProfiles' is based on type 'UserProfile' that has no keys defined.

I believe this error has something to do with trying to use EF on a table that is not in an edmx model.  I have not added any of the simplemembership tables (UserProfile, Membership, Roles, etc) into my edmx file because when I do that I get errors of duplicate classes, I'm guessing because the SM tables are created code first.

I have never done any code first, does the answer lay there? Or do I need to add the SM tables to my edmx model so I can query them.  If so, how do I get around teh duplicate class error?

I have the 2 seperate connection strings in my web config.

EDIT++++++++++

I have been researching and found a different way, but I get the same error.

```
                int id;
                using (var db = new UsersContext())
                {
                    var user = db.UserProfiles.Find(model.UserName);
                    id = user.UserId;
                }
```

I get the error on the 'using' line.  Here is the code for the UsersContext:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("SecurityEntities")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

"SecurityEntities is the connection string which looks like:

```
   <add name="SecurityEntities" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=OurAgreements;user id=oaadmin;password=136VDSyPLrcfgPfw3BIH;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Can you see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your definition for *UserProfile* look like. It should look something like this:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    ...
 }
```

The *Key* attribute indicates that the *UserId* is the key and the *DatabaseGeneratedAttribute* indicates that the *UserId* value is generated by the database.  The error you are getting seems to indicate you do not have the *Key* attribute on your *UserProfile* definition.

**Updated 5/29/13**

If you are having trouble with changing the schema for UserProfile and it is not setup for migration take a look at this article that shows [how to customize and seed SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html). The setup in this article is geared more towards development and testing your application.  There is another article on [setting up database migration for SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/04/using-code-first-migration-with.html).

Comment: Thank you Kevin for responding.  I add the key and identity attributes, which made it possible to execute the query, but it comes back null.  I then added the 'Table' attribute and it errored out saying the database has changed and I should use migrations.  Can't I just get rid of the UserProfile model, and add the table to my edmx file and use as a normal ef connection?  i have never done code first.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, null, false);
var ID = WebSecurity.GetUserId(model.UserName);
```

and it works well for me